# Converting ToShortDateString converted datetime back to datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can a date like '20/11/2013' - string be converted to this format
2013-11-20 00:00:00.000 in c# using
DateTime.ParseExact or any other function.

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact, i am concerned about the 00:00:00.000 part

Comment: You want to add `00:00:00.000` to the end of your string? Can you not just concatenate the strings? Perhaps you should post the code you've already got...

Answer (score 3):

Using DateTime.ParseExact you can do it as mentioned below :

```
    var stringToConvert = "20/11/2013";
    var convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(stringToConvert, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

   // dd : date
   // MM : minute
   // yyyy : year
   // hh : hour
   // mm : minute
   // ss : second
    var dateFormatMMddYYYY = convertedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
    var dateFormatddMMYYYY = convertedDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    var dateFormatyyyyMMdd = convertedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

**Note** : Before converting to datetime make sure that your string is able to convert to the datetime.

You can use **Datetime.TryParse** function for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **DateTime.TryParse(...)** method.

```
var dtString = "01/01/2000 01:00:00 AM";
DateTime dt;
var converted = DateTime.TryParse(dtString, out dt);
if (converted) {
    // Converted okay.
    var newFormat = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
    // Outputs: 2001/01/01 01:00:00
} else {
    // Failed to convert.
}
```

This is handy as it'll allow you to check if the DateTime string specified converted okay.

Answer (score 0):

```
string originalShortDateTime = "20/11/2013";
string inputFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(originalShortDateTime, 
inputFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //or a specific culture
```

We'll then output the preferred format using a `DateTime.ToString()` with argument:

```
string outputDateString = result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: shouldn't that be "yyyy-MM-dd"?